# What does the MiniWallet class currently do and need to do in the Bitcoin Core functional test framework?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, functional-test

I tried to run the Taproot functional tests after building Bitcoin Core with the wallet disabled (as I knew there was no Taproot code in the Core wallet at the time of writing, December 2020).

However, they were skipped because a number of the functional tests currently rely on the Core wallet to create and sign transactions. (Thanks to Marco Falke for pointing this out on IRC.)

The introduction of [MiniWallet](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19800) though raises the prospect of being able to update these non-wallet functional tests so they no longer rely on the Core wallet.

There is a [good first issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20078) open on the Bitcoin Core repo to do this for all non-wallet tests. As Marco states in that issue:

> This is an open-ended issue. You can find candidate tests via
> `git grep self.skip_if_no_wallet()`. Exclude the tests that start with `wallet_`, as those are tests that are meant to test the Bitcoin Core wallet.

So what does the [MiniWallet class](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/functional/test_framework/wallet.py#L28) currently do (and perhaps need to do) so that all non-wallet functional tests can be rewritten to no longer rely on the Core wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, `MiniWallet` doesn't do any signing. It generates an address and sends an effective regtest coinbase to it. It then constructs an OP_TRUE transaction that spends to yourself with a fee.

I'm not sure at this stage if this is enough to replace the reliance on the Core wallet for all non-wallet functional tests but I will look into it more.

MiniWallet is [not](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20692#issuecomment-747802638) a wallet handled by the node, it is an "external" wallet coded in Python for testing. gettransaction only works for those wallets handled by the node, that's why the error says: non-wallet transaction id